# CSS: Is "p div.myclass" a valid selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is `p div.myclass` a valid CSS selector?
I'd like to select div.myclass but only when it is a descendent of p.

```
<body>
 <div class="myclass">Do not select</div>
  <p>
    <any>...
      <div class="myclass">Select this element to set background & border
        <any>Other stuff may be here</any>
      </div>
    </any>
   </p>
  </div> <!-- added this after question was answered -->
</body>
```

Comment: divs shouldn't be embedded in p, but otherwise, yes, it's valid.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? If you're more interested in whether it's technically valid, run it through a validator.

Comment: Not entirely sure why this is getting downvoted and, um, *flagged*. There's nothing wrong with this question, except for a snippet of markup that looks quite silly at first blush.

Comment: I didn't realize that div couldn't be used within a p.  That may explain other oddities I am seeing.

Answer (score 5):

It's a valid selector, yes; but a `div` is not a valid child of a `p` element. So the CSS is valid, but the HTML to which you're applying that selector is invalid.

Incidentally, apart from the nested `div` within the `p`, you've also got an unclosed `div` wrapping the `p`, which is followed by the `</body>` tag. So your HTML is doubly-invalid, as tags must be closed in the reverse order in which they're opened.

Addenda, as raised in the comments (I wasn't going to bother adding this originally, instead planning to focus on the syntax of the CSS), the browser (certainly Chromium 24/Ubuntu 12.10) 'rescues' your HTML when it constructs the DOM, so you go from this:

```
<p>
    <any>...
        <div class="myclass">Select this element to set background & border
            <any>Other stuff may be here</any>
        </div>
    </any>
</p>
```

To a DOM that looks like this (again, in Chromium 24/Ubuntu 12.10):

```
<p>
    <any>...</any>
</p>
<div class="myclass">Select this element to set background &amp; border
    <any>Other stuff may be here</any>
</div>
<p></p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dWz6M/).

Therefore if the problem you have, and the reason you're asking the question, is that the [CSS isn't selecting/styling an element](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dWz6M/1/), the reason is simply because you're using invalid HTML, and the browser's changing your HTML while constructing the (valid) DOM, which means the selector no longer matches what you were originally targeting.

This is why HTML validity rules should be followed, it makes it easier to work with (both today, and in future when you, or someone else has to, revisit).

Oh, and finally, also the `&` character should *not* be used in HTML directly, it should be encoded in some way, such as `&amp;`, because the `&` character is the first character in HTML character-entity codes. So...you've created *triply* invalid HTML.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the div breaks the p.

Comment: The HTML is salvaged by the browser when it constructs the DOM (I think, I haven't tested it, yet), but the CSS syntax is valid. Which is the explicit question being answered. Note that I do say the *HTML...is invalid*.

Comment: you are correct no doubt. I was just thinking, like when you try to nest `<p>` tags, they break each other and start a new element instead of a descendant. I think the same thing happens with a div in a p.

Comment: Incidentally, you're absolutely right: [Chromium 24/Ubuntu 12.10](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dWz6M/) salvages the HTML and corrects it while building the DOM.

Comment: Great answer. For the sake of completeness, this behavior is in fact consistent across all modern browsers. HTML can be such a pain.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm linux-only, are you able to comment on the results with IE? I ask, mainly because you specify 'modern browsers,' so perhaps for curiosity only. Also, my thanks! =)

Comment: IE in standards mode does also behave the same, yes. I generally consider IE9 and newer to be in the same league as the other modern browsers :)

Comment: As do I, I was curious (though didn't specify) IE 7 or 8? IE 10 I consider, through various reviews, to be a pretty good example of a browser and standards-compliance, IE 9 I'm unsure of, since I've no experience of it, and I don't recall the reviews. =)

Comment: I think it's consistent all the way back to antiquity.

Comment: The missing </div> was a mistake in my example.  As mentioned above, I didn't realize <div> couldn't be ancestor of <p>.  I guess I was expecting Dreamweaver to tell me such things.

Comment: A `div` *can* be an ancestor (parent, grandparent, etc...) of a `p`, it simply can't be a *descendant* (child, grandchild, etc).

Comment: It helps... ;) don't worry about it too much, just be prepared to accept (*hopefully civil*) corrections from time-to-time, and realise that they're not intended as personal insults or attacks is all =)